# clear cache of one image

Tags: php, caching

Consider the minimal example: Using php I have a form that you enter text and it produces an image of the text. When I then change the text and update, I don't see the new image because I assume, it is being cached. Is there some way to automatically remove this one image file from the cache when I update it?

Comment: try to change the version of the image being generated for example your image name?j=1 where j=1 or 2 or 3 is the version being change

Comment: Provide more details please.

Comment: How does the browser load the image? Via a full page reload or by means of some "Ajaxy" magic?

Comment: @Spontifixus I don't know, I just hit reload (sometimes with a shift).

Comment: That's a full page reload. @ceejayoz answer will fix your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is frequently handled by adding a random string or timestamp to the query.

i.e. `<img src="/images/image.jpg?timestamp=1357571065" />`

Comment: can I put any number in that string, or does it need to generated automatically somehow?

Comment: Ok, I have this working. I have also found: `lastmod` instead of `timestamp`, does this make a difference?

Comment: @Geoff A last modified date would be perfect, as the cache would only be cleared when the image is changed.

Comment: The cache is _never_ cleared because of that additional argument. Why should it? That is no magical way to say: forget that content!. It is simply different urls in each request which is why no cached object is used.

Comment: @arkascha It accomplishes the desired affect - browsers see it as a different URL, so they see the new version of the static asset. Useful when you need to, say, revise a site's logo and it's been served with a far-future expiration date.

Comment: You got me wrong: I absolutely agree with you that this workaround, well, works... My answer just reflected your additional comment claiming that cached objects are cleared. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is what ceejazoz gave in this answer: an additional timestamp added as a request parameter. That way the url is different each time, so no cache or proxy will deliver a cached version.

However although that works it is an ugly workaround.

The clean solution is to specify headers when delivering the image. Those headers take care that the image is not cached. That is what headers are there for: defining *how* resources are meant to be used. The drawback: the out-of-the-box configuration of todays http servers used to deliver static images does *not* offer to specify such headers. Because in 99,99% of all cases it makes no sense. So you will have to write an own mechanism. Not really difficult, but effort nonetheless. Using the above workaround certainly is easier and less hassle.

And to give a precise answer to your actual question: 
Cleaning 'the' cache from a single cached object usually is not possible. Though that actually depends on what cache you are talking about. If it is just the browsers cache whilst you are developing (testing), then just make a 'deep reload' (something like CTRL-SHIFT-R or CTRL-F5, depending on your browser). But this clears *all* cached objects of the current page. There is no easy way to clear a server side cache or even a proxy inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Add a query string to the image perhaps containing the julian time + a random number so for example your image URL becomes:
//.../myimage.jpg?112233445566-954967254

Answer (score 0):

You can re validate the cache
       `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`

Comment: That won't do much good if the image is already long-term cached for a user, though.