# PHP : Updating new image still showing the old image

Tags: php

So I am creating a new folder everytime if folder not exists using mdkir.

```
$dir_name = '../../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortfolio/';

if(!is_dir($dir_name)){
    mkdir('../../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortolfio/', 0777, true);
}
```

Now I am trying to update my uploaded image on that folder. And its working fine when i look on that designated directory

```
$static_name = $event_id."d".$getThed1d2."_contestant_";
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$theRealName = $static_name.$lastDigit.".".$extension;
echo $theRealName;
```

But when i try to get the image why is it still showing up the old image instead the new one?

```
<img class="img_here_edit" src="../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortfolio/'.$soc_sql['images'].'" width="100%" >
```

I doubt but I'm not sure that its on my new created directory mdkir which has 0777 because those of my code are working fine in my other regular folder? How do i solve this

Comment: If you refresh the page you still get the old image? The image might be in the browser's cache...

Comment: Yes, when i refresh the old image not replacing with new one, I try to delete cache and its working but, on my other file it replace without deleting my cahe

Comment: could you provide the link from your web page that corresponds to src="../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortfolio/'.$soc_sql['images']. It could be you updating one file and displaying another

Comment: Did you try renaming the old image ?

Comment: Yes if rename its working fine but i need to remain the old name, Btw I am using ajax on getting the image

Comment: Ok i solve it by adding unique string on the query src="../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortfolio/'.$soc_sql['images'].'?'.$unique.'" i found the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197493/clear-cache-of-one-image)

Answer (score 0):

use unlink(''); function to old image it will solve your problem

Comment: Is old image name same as the new uploaded image, and check if you are getting image name from Database change it with new image name

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete the old image and create and upload a new image with the same name?.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a random id at the end of image url to get the latest image like this :

```
<img class="img_here_edit" src="../assets/contestant_double/'.$event_id.'eventPortfolio/'.$soc_sql['images'].'?'.time().'" width="100%" >
```

Answer (score 0):

what you see is the picture on browser cache, so you have to clear cache of browser. however, you wont do that every time you replace a picture either your users, it is too tedious and unpractical. I had same sutation and what i did was the follown. create filename + time().jpg like this.
So by the time i was going to replace old picture, i loaded from folder, delete it an then place new one. look...

```
    function uploadphoto( $id, $ref ) {
    $find = $ref.'_';
    $data = $_POST[ 'image' ];
    list( $type, $data ) = explode( ';', $data );
    list( , $data ) = explode( ',', $data );
    $data = base64_decode( $data );
    $imageName = $ref.'_'.time().'.jpg'; // new picture name
    
    foreach(glob('uploads/'.$find.'*.*') as $filename){
        $localizacion = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'. $filename ;
            chmod('./uploads', 0777);
            unlink($localizacion);
    }

    file_put_contents( 'uploads/' . $imageName, $data );
```

}